# Hibernate performance in terms of reads and writes

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, database-performance, cpu-cache

How does hibernate works in terms of reads and writes:

1. How hibernate works if the application does more writes to DB?
   In this case i understand that the cache has to be refreshed for every write, apart from this is the any performance overhead (in compared with JDBC)
2. How hibernate works if the application just read data(very less write/update)?
   In this case as cache is not required to be refreshed can we expect the performance of hibernate to be as good(or better) as JDBC(if tuned properly).

Also, want to understand the best option to use(apart from ORM) in case2.

Comment: Do you want to use level 2 cache? EHCache for example? It is quite important.

Comment: Yes, we may also use level2 chache. But, for now i want to understand the performance in general. And want to understand if using ORM in case2 will have major performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra layer is always less performant. However, this extra layer sometimes will also reduce development time. So it all depends upon your usecase and performance requirements. If you use ORM then you can enable 2nd level caching for reads and queries and that is your application level performance. But sometimes the native DB caching is quite enough (this way each node in cluster can avoid caching).

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is a tool that might make development much easier. I feel (based on my own experiences) that Hibernate overhead is not very large. You'll probably end up with writing your own sql result to objects mapping. It might be slighly faster than Hibernate's if you're good. However:

- Hibernate does L1 caching in session so you don't need to remember if you got the data from DB or not
- Hibernate performance tunning is much easier than JDBC - just plug Javamelody on live app and look for the slowest SQLs then play with eager and lazy loading to make things faster. No need of SQL rewriting nor touching mapping code. You just need to tune some annotations
- L2 caching is quite easy. Sometimes DB caching does the trick, but it has its limits. In Hibernate you can enable relations caching and query caching. You'll see the difference when you DB is a bottleneck and your application is deployed on several nodes. Distributed cache will be much faster than hitting DB thousands of times.

So to conclude, yes, Hibernate has its overhead, but for me tuning capabilites are very important and it is possible (and very likely) to have better performance with Hibernate than with plain JDBC in a complicated application. I don't need to say that developenent with Hibernate and QueryDSL is way faster than with plain JDBC.